# Always up to date content using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

At the moment I am using ajax requests every 10 minutes to update certain content and other time intervals for others.

I do this using jQuery by:

- On mouse move, the active page is checked
- If the active page has not be updated within the given time interval, the page is updated

I'm doing this because although i want the content to stay up to date, I don't want it to be sending requests in the background (when the user is not using the application). Doing this also means that if the user has not used it for more than the time period, when they start to use it again it will automatically update.

I'm wondering just how efficient this is as whenever the mouse moves the checks are called (and has slowed down performance a bit - especially when trying to click links) - is the a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a great way to do this! Never thought of doing it this way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather activate/reset a timer, on say, 60 seconds, on movement of the mouse, and set your fixed-interval checks to only run if that timer is above zero.

That way, checks aren't made every time the mouse moves, and if the user becomes inactive, update checks stop after 60 seconds.

Comment: So when page loads initiate the timer.
When the mouse moves reset the timer to 60.
The timer counts down until it reaches 0.
At the set interval, check if the timer is greater than 0, if it is the user is active (greater than 0) the page updates, else it does not.

The problem with this is that if the user has been away for 10 minutes, the update will have just been checked just before they came active and will not be checked for another 10 minutes?

Comment: So reset the fixed-interval checks timers, if the movement timer is zero (user has been inactive) when reset to 60.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to use the window `blur` and `focus` events to determine if the window is active:

```
var checkForContentUpdates = true;

$(window).focus(function() {
    checkForContentUpdates = true;
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    checkForContentUpdates = false;
});
```

Your AJAX routine would then key off of the `checkForContentUpdates` bool.

I'm sure that there are scenarios where this isn't fool-proof, so you'd likely have to combine this method with other logic.

Comment: I suppose this could work, in addition to my current logic which checks how long since the update was called so on window focus i would run the check and update accordingly.

Comment: The only problem i can see with this is that if the user leaves the window focused and wonders away from their pc, it will still update... if this is combined with the method above however it may work perfectly - without causing performance issues